# Spark SQL returns null for max on string column

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

My Hive table is multi-partitioned as follows

`hive -e "show partitions mydb.mytab;"`

```
date_part=2018-10-11/att_name=asd
date_part=2018-10-12/att_name=qwe
date_part=2018-10-13/att_name=zxc
date_part=2018-10-14/att_name=asd
date_part=2018-10-15/att_name=qwe
date_part=2018-10-16/att_name=asd
```

Note that `date_part` and `att_name` are both stored as **string**s

now, I want to know what the latest partition is for `att_name=zxc` and get the `date_part` value. Considering the data above, I am looking for `2018-10-13` as for the other dates, I dont have the partition corresponding to `att_name=zxc`. So, when i perform the following hive query,

`hive -e "select max(date_part) from mydb.mytab where att_name = 'zxc'"`

I get

`2018-10-13`

which is perfect.

Next, I tried doing the same thing with spark sql

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

lazy val sparkSess = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("myApp")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
sparkSess.sql("select max(date_part) from mydb.mytab where att_name = 'zxc'").show()
```

but for this, I get

```
+--------------+
|max(date_part)|
+--------------+
|          null|
+--------------+
```

I think its because `date_part` is a string column. but then why does hive query not have a problem?

What am I doing wrong?

Is this the correct way to conditionally get the latest partition from a multi-partitioned table?

**Table Description**

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.bfd-puppet/hive-log4j.properties
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment

id                      string
value                   string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

date_part               string
att_name                string

# Detailed Table Information
Database:               mydb
Owner:                  mytab
CreateTime:             some timestamp
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               maprfs:/path/to/hive/mydb.db/mytab
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE
Table Parameters:
    EXTERNAL                TRUE
    transient_lastDdlTime   136786171357

# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
    serialization.format    1
Time taken: 0.201 seconds, Fetched: 34 row(s)
```

**Print Schema**

so, for the query I am trying to execute,

```
scala> val bsv1 = sess.sql(s"SELECT max(date_part) FROM mydb.mytab WHERE att_name='zxc'")
bsv1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [max(date_part): string]

scala> bsv1.printSchema()
root
 |-- max(date_part): string (nullable = true)


scala>
```

however, when I try a different query

```
scala> val bsv1 = sess.sql(s"SELECT * FROM mydb.mytab WHERE date_part='2018-12-01' and att_name='zxc'")
18/12/12 10:02:28 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
bsv1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, value: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> bsv1.printSchema
   def printSchema(): Unit

scala> bsv1.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_part: string (nullable = true)
 |-- att_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what spark version you are on?

Comment: i have 2.2.0 version

Comment: can you share hive `desc formatted` for that table, and also `printSchema` ?

Comment: thanks @shay__ I have updated the post